# Display selected picture under it's button with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry the title is not better. Here is where I'm at. I am trying to open an openFileDialog, then display the image I picked below that button. I can do it fine with one button and one image. However I can't seem to get the selected picture to show under only the appropriate button. My script looks like this.

```js
$('.custom-upload input[type=file]').change(function() {
  var parentCommentId = $(this).id
  $(this).next().find('input').val($(this).val());

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }

  function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $('img').fadeIn();
  };
});
```

```css
.custom-upload {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.custom-upload input[type=file] {
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity: 0);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.custom-upload .fake-file {
  background: url(http://www.fold3.com/i/upload-icon.png) center right no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.custom-upload .fake-file input {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-upload" id="taco">
  <input type="file" id="eatme">
  <div class="fake-file">
    <input disabled="disabled" id="damn">
  </div>
  <img id="myImg" src="#" style="display: none;height:400px;" width=100% height=100%/>
</div>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="custom-upload">
  <input type="file">
  <div class="fake-file">
    <input disabled="disabled">

  </div>
  <img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" style="display: none;" width=100% />
</div>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using `parentCommentId`, but if you do you'll need to change `$(this).id` to `this.id`.

Comment: Why don't you simply use file upload `multiple`?

Comment: Thanks guys. It's been years since i have really done anything in javascript. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$("img")` selects *all* img elements. You need to use [DOM navigation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to get from the input for which the change event occurred to its related img element.

```
$('.custom-upload input[type=file]').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);  // store a reference to current input
  $this.next().find('input').val($(this).val());

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }

  function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $this.closest('.custom-upload')
         .find('img')
         .attr('src', e.target.result)
         .fadeIn();
  };
});
```

I've saved a reference to the current file input in the (new) variable `$this`. Then in the img onload handler I've used `.closest()` to navigate up to the containing div and then `.find()` to go back down to the img in that div.

(You could use `$this.siblings("img")` or `$this.next().next()`, but that would only work for your specific html structure as it is right now - using `.closest()` plus `.find()` will work even if you later add an extra (sub-)container div around the img or otherwise tweak the structure, just as long as the file input and img are still within the same containing div.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jndL3rj5/